# Does choice of DBMS matter for protection against XSS and other injection attacks?

Tags: xss, databases, mysql, sql-server, mongodb

I am choosing between the three most used databases, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server and MongoDB. I have to choose the most secure database from these three.

Does my choice of DBMS has a role in protecting against XSS attacks and other similar attacks, or are they prevented only through only secure frontend and backend programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> protection against XSS attacks ...

XSS is an attack against the client side, not the server side where the DBMS resides. Thus the choice of DBMS does not matter here.

> ... and other similar attacks

I'm not sure what you consider similar attacks. But when talking about DBMS the main attack vector is SQL injection and in case of NoSQL DBMS like MongoDB NoSQL injection.

> Does my choice of DBMS has a role in protection against ... attacks, or is it prevented only through only secure frontend and backend programming?

To protect against SQL/NoSQL injection you better make sure that you choose a DBMS where you don't need to construct query strings from user input but can use techniques like parameter binding - see [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/) for more details on this.

Apart from that you really should thoroughly verify all user input, and doubly so if your DBMS does not support things like parameter binding.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, my question is regarding stored and reflected XSS attacks involve sending attack payload to the server so that it is displayed back to the client as legitimate web content

Comment: @PraveenDavidMathew: As I said, XSS are solely  attacks against the client side. The DBMS only stores data (in case of stored XSS) and with reflected XSS the DBMS is not even involved. Thus, the choice of DBMS does not matter in case of XSS and the protection against XSS has to be done in the application logic and not the DBMS.

Comment: Thank you so much, is there anyway DBMS knows it's a xss payload ? And prevent it

Comment: @PraveenDavidMathew: A DBMS is a data storage. It has no idea where the string stored in the database will ever be used by the application and thus has no idea if it can be used for XSS or not.

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL, Microsoft SQL server and mangoDB. I have to choose the most
>   secure database from these three.

That's personal preference what you choose.

> Does my choice of DBMS has a role in protection against XSS attacks

No.**XSS** is caused mainly by mishandling of user input,**choice of database cannot prevent an XSS attack**

> other similar attacks

That's hard to say.But vulnerability like **SQL** injection will exist in every DBMS.

> or is it prevented only through only secure frontend and backend
>   programming

Absolutely.When it comes to web application most attacks are caused by improper validation of user input when it reaches the server.

Comment: Mango is a fruit ;-)

Comment: @bradbury9 haha.I didnt write it though,i copy pasted it from the question